Active directory на сервере 2012r2 и маршрутизатор
Необходимо закинуть 20-30 пк в домен AD на сервер 2012r2. Сделал все по мануалу поднял  DNS и DHCP, прописал статический ip. Все в одной сети на маршрутизаторе + роутер для интернета.
На пк юзера пингуется и днс и сам dc. Но дальше аутентификации ничего не происходит, ошибка, не верный путь или сервер отключён.
Сам же думаю на то, что не правильно прописал пути.
Кто может помочь? Сам я программист и далёк от от локальных сетей.
